# Check if all values in a specific column has an exact value to update dataverse cell with this another value

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, power-automate, powerapps, dataverse

I have 3 dataverse tables, Projects, Tasks, and Sub-tasks where the schema goes as follows
Tasks has a lookup column for projects, and Sub-tasks has a lookup column for Tasks.

Each table Has ID as auto-increment (acts as FK in the other table), with the addition of Sub-tasks table has 1 more column which is Status_ID (which is a lookup column for table Statuses)

What I want to do,

I want to use Power Automate to check for all sub-tasks who got status_id = 1 and task_id equal so in that case I'll update the projects table with some kind of value as Done.

I know that I should use a trigger for when a row is updated/created/deleted, then maybe I should list rows for the data and start filtering them, but actually, I'm new to the Power platform, and Power Automate so I feel a little bit lost.

I would appreciate it if someone would guide me through it.

Answer (score 0):

hows it going. you can use a trigger on the sub task table to run every time the status gets updated and query the sub tasks related to the project to check. Once you have queried using the list rows with probably a fetch XML, you can then use power automate functions to group and filter accordingly. However this would run several times so i would suggest including a condition statement early on in the flow to control actions as well as in the trigger if you want to run it only for a specific status